# Altering specific rows of a multidimensional list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

What is a way of going through a bidimensional ArrayList> and for specific rows you subtract one (but not for all, just basically there is a boolean T/F check prior to this, if the boolean is T then do this) All I keep coming up with is what essentially ends up being infinite for loops

The change has to be done only for specific rows of the list... i.e.: (FOR purposes of getting this to work, elig.get(0) is false)

if I have:
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 2], [2, 1, 1], [3, 6, 1], [1, 6, 3]] I would want to get (for ex.) in the

1st and last rows are to be -1 so :
[[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 2], [2, 1, 1], [3, 6, 1], [0, 5, 2]]

and so forth

code I have now is: (I isolated it, and really have no idea why this does not work?

```
for(int j=0; j<(bigArr.size()); j++) {   

            for(int k=0; k<(bigArr.get(0).size()); k++) {   

                if(elig.get(0) == false) {  

                bigArr.get(j).set(k, ballotArr.get(j).get(k)-1);



            }

        }
System.out.println(ballotArr);     
}
```

Comment: Is it arraylist of arrays ? or arraylist of arraylists ?

Comment: what problem is your code giving to you till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just like having an ArrayList of ArrayList. So instead of referring to a specific element in a normal array like arr[row][column], it would be arr.get(row).get(column)

```
//loops through first dimension
for(int row=0;row<myList.size();row++) {
    //check that T/F you mentioned
    if(myBoolean) {
        //loop through second dimension
        for(int i=0;i<myList.get(row).size();i++) {
            //subtract 1 from everything in second dimension
            myList.get(row).set(i, myList.get(row).get(i)-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me the same problem (using my original example), the new arraylist of arraylists is just [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
List<List<Integer>> nums = ...;

if (nums.size() >= 2) {
    subtractOneFromRow(nums, 0);
    subtractOneFromRow(nums, nums.size() - 1);
} else if (nums.size() == 1) {
    subtractOneFromRow(nums, 0);
}
// Do nothing if there are no rows

// ...

private static void subtractOneFromRow(List<List<Integer>> nums, int r) {
    List<Integer> row = nums.get(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < row.size(); c++) {
        row.set(c, row.get(c) - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new at this...so nums = my big 2d arraylist and r = just for this?
I am not following this that well either, if(nums.size()>=2 then still subtract from the rows? the code I have I am editing in, but it subtracts 1 from the first 'false' one and replaces the entire bigArr with that